# Hi, i have integrate my selenium script with jenkins but i am not able to launch the chrome browser

Tags: java, ubuntu, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

i have integrate my selenium script with jenkins but i am not able to launch the chrome browser, i have tried almost every solutions and in my machine there is chrome version Version 75.0.3770.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) and 75 version supported chrome driver is available.

in jenkins i am getting

> Starting ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.90
>   (a6dcaf7e3ec6f70a194cc25e8149475c6590e025-refs/branch-heads/3770@{#1003})
>   on port 21983 Only local connections are allowed. Please protect ports
>   used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by
>   malicious code. Tests run: 7, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 6, Time
>   elapsed: 1.332 sec <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
>   beforeMethod(qa.Vehicle_registration)  Time elapsed: 1.206 sec  <<<
>   FAILURE! org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:  unknown error:
>   Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally   (unknown error:
>   DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)   (The process started from
>   chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so
>   ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) Build info:
>   version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time:
>   '2017-08-29T12:42:44.417Z' System info: host:
>   'administrator-Latitude-3480', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux',
>   os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.15.0-52-generic', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_11' Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver remote
>   stacktrace: #0 0x55c60975b6e9

I have tried below code but still i am getting same error.

```
public class Google{
  WebDriver driver;  

  @BeforeClass
  public void beforeMethod() throws IOException, InterruptedException 
  {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/home/ashishtiwari/driver/chromedriver");

      ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

      options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
      options.addArguments("start-maximized"); // open Browser in maximized mode
      options.addArguments("disable-infobars"); // disabling infobars
      options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); // disabling extensions
      options.addArguments("--disable-gpu"); // applicable to windows os only
      options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); // overcome limited resource problems
      options.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); // Bypass OS security model
      options.addArguments("--headless");
      options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
      driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
      driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
         driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(utill.ashu, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(utill.sonam, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //http://tmsapp.xbees.in/#/dashboard
          driver.get("https://google.com");
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please edit your question, as it's not well-formatted

Comment: Make sure that the selenium version supports the browser version.

Comment: Try after removing `driver.manage().window().maximize();` option. There is no window to maximize.

Comment: i have tried  after removing driver.manage().window().maximize(); but still getting same error.

Comment: This code is successful running on my eclipse but on jenkins server i am getting "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)"

Comment: i have checked chrome installed location also, and chrome is running fine in this location /usr/bin/google-chrome , this is my default chrome location.

Answer (score 0):

1. I got the same problem while launching the chrome browser using selenium in visual studio code.I solved this issue by deleting chromedriver.exe from my project as I created so many Chromedriver.exe file.Just check is there more than one chromedriver.exe file is there in your project.
2. chromedriver.exe file should be in bin/debug/net5.0/chromedriver.exe.
3. If  you follow above steps then there is no need to give the local path for chrome driver.